# Toast message for including recipent's name or Spinner ID when SMS is sent

Tags: android, sms, messaging, toast, android-spinner

my application is where user sends a well-wishing message. It has Spinner which contains the recipents' names and they're hardcoded. I've created a Toast message says"SMS is sent successfully". but I realize I need to include a certain recipent's name in the Toast message to confirm that the message is sent to the recipent.

I've tried whatever Toast messages I know to try to include the recipent's name but I get errors and the Toast  message failed when I run the app. I'll post the full codes of the SMS app.

```
public class SMSEvents extends Activity
{
    Button btnSMS;
    EditText messageTxt;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    TextView text, textName;
    Spinner sendTo;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String friends[] = {"Kanak Priya", "Joanne Liew", "Melissa Haiting", "Michelle Lam", "Teo Kin Hua", "David Yeo", "Nur Ashiqin", "Stephanie"};

    private int namesSpinnderId;

    private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                // ---display the SMS received in the TextView---
                TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("sms"));                          
            }                       
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sms);

        sendTo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sendTo);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinner_text, friends);
        sendTo.setAdapter(adapter);





        /*BuddyDBAdapter buddyDB = new BuddyDBAdapter(this);

        sendTo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sendTo);
        Cursor friendsCursor = buddyDB.getAllNames();
        startManagingCursor(friendsCursor);*/

        /*String[] from = new String[]{BuddyDBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.sendTo};

        SimpleCursorAdapter friendsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, friendsCursor, from, to);
        friendsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sendTo.setAdapter(friendsAdapter);*/

       /* sendTo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
                {
                    Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                    namesSpinnderId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BuddyDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID));                  
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });*/

        // ---intent to filter for SMS messages received---
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        // ---register the receiver---
        registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);

        //sendTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendTo);
        //textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textName);


        sendTo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sendTo);
        messageTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageTxt);

        btnSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSMS);
        btnSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    String contact_name = sendTo.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String message = messageTxt.getText().toString();

                    if (contact_name.length() > 0 && message.length() > 0)
                        sendSMS(contact_name, message);
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getBaseContext(),
                                "Please enter your message",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    /*Intent msgIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    msgIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content");
                    msgIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                    startActivity(msgIntent);*/
                }

            });

        Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMain);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0)
                {
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent(SMSEvents.this, MainPage.class);
                    startActivity(menuIntent);

                }
            });


    }




    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // ---register the receiver---
        // registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        // ---unregister the receiver---
        // unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        // ---unregister the receiver---
        unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void sendSMS(String contact_name, String message)
    {
        String SENT = "SMS SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        // ---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
                {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                        {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS is sent to" +contact_name successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service failure",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null Pdu",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
                {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                        {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage("5554", null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        //sms.sendTextMessage(contact_name, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);

        /*try
        {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(contact_name, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS is sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS failed! Please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }
}
```

The `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS is sent to" +contact_name successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` which I'm trying to do to include the recipent's name.

If anyone knows how to do this Toast, I'll appreciate it =). Sorry for asking a simple help but I tried 3 different ways of doing this kind of Toast message.

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this Toast.

You code this Toast message in `public void onReceive()` which is within `private void sendSMS()`

like this:

`Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS is sent to "  +sendTo.getSelectedItem()+  " successfully.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

The `getSelectedItem()` is getting selected item from Spinner. IF you're using EditText or TextView, just replace `getSelectedItem()` with `getText()`

:D, those whoever has similar problem to mine, can try this answer out and hope it solves their similar problems. :D